# How to differentiate tasks from master project and subprojects

Tags: vsto, ms-office, ms-project

Using the Microsoft Project VSTO, I am able to iterate through all the Tasks in a project.

The problem with this approach is that if a file has one master project and multiple subprojects, the Tasks collection for the master project will contain tasks from ALL the projects (master as well as subprojects).

Is there someway to differentiate whether the Task is from a master project or a subproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easies way is `Task.Project` that will return you name of a project your task belongs to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863203.aspx) also you can get name of a subproject from it's "ancor" task in your master through `Task.Subproject` [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office.vbapj.chm132614.aspx). There is also a field which tells you if the subproject is Read-Only or you can update it: `Task.SubProjectReadOnly` [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861429.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access only the main project, it might be quicker to start with the summary task and recursively deal with each task's children, stopping the recursion on tasks which represent external subprojects.  That way, you will not have to touch every task.